# Apply function across mulitple columns in R

Tags: r, loops, lapply, sapply

I'm trying to write a streamlined function in R to compare multiple columns in a matrix. What is the optimal way to do this in R? Most likely using apply.

I have seen this question crop up a number of times but with some conflicting views on the optimal way to write this.

```
for ( j in 2:ncol(net) )
{
    for ( i in 1:nrow(net) )
    {
            net[i,j] <- min(net[i,j],net[i,1])
    }
}
```

The end output of a matrix with the following

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    2    3
[3,]    3    2    3
```

would be

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2
[3,]    3    2    3
```

Comment: This is quite confusing for me to read, since `i` is universally used to index rows; and `j` columns. In particular, you will see these names in the help file `help("[")`

Comment: I have edited this in the original now, and updated the question with an example.

Comment: The input you showed is not a `data.frame`.  It is a `matrix`.  So, please don't confuse others with your description.

Comment: Have now re-edited the wording

Comment: @user2065472 Would you like to accept one of the given answers? ... by clicking next to the voting. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no `NA`s you can do

```
net <- head(airquality, 4) # example data
for (j in 1:nrow(net)) net[j, net[j,]>net[j,1]] <- net[j,1]
net
```

Comment: This solution gives the desired result, and is much quicker than my double for loop, but I still feel could be sped up (how I'm not exactly sure)...

Comment: IMO a signifcant speed up isn't possible in R because on the lower level the operation is now vectorized. The coding certainly could be mor compact, but I suppose that would be loop-hiding.

Answer (score 1):

We can `unlist` the columns the "net" except the first column (`net[-1]`), replicate the first column as the same length as the `unlist`ed columns, and use `pmin` to get the minimum value of corresponding elements of the `vectors`.

```
pmin(unlist(net[-1], use.names=FALSE), net[,1][row(net[-1])])
#[1] 2 2 7 5 2 2 2 6 5 3 2 1 0 5 1
```

If we need a `lapply` solution,

```
unlist(lapply(net[-1], function(x) pmin(x, net[,1])), use.names=FALSE)
```

Using the OP's `for` loop

```
for ( i in 2:ncol(net) ){
   for ( j in 1:nrow(net) ){
     print(min(net[j,i],net[j,1]))
   }
 }
#[1] 2
#[1] 2
#[1] 7
#[1] 5
#[1] 2
#[1] 2
#[1] 2
#[1] 6
#[1] 5
#[1] 3
#[1] 2
#[1] 1
#[1] 0
#[1] 5
#[1] 1
```

#### Update

As the OP mentioned that this is not giving the expected output, trying with new data  showed in the OP's post

```
net <- cbind(1:3, 2, 3)

cbind(net[,1],pmin(unlist(net[,-1], use.names=FALSE), 
           net[,1][row(net[,-1])]))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    1
#[2,]    2    2    2
#[3,]    3    2    3
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
net <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:9, 4*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=4))
```

Comment: Wouldn't this only give the min of the column though rather than the min of the specific two cell comparison i.e. I'm comparing the min of the value of the first column/row value to each row/column value after that?

Comment: @user2065472 It is better to provide a reproducible example.  Can you try the updated solution?

Comment: This won't work if there are three columns. The matrix subsetting will kick in producing an out of bounds error. Try `net <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:9, 3*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=3))`

Comment: @PierreLafortune  I think `net[,1]` should make it work.

Comment: Yes that will avoid the method dispatch.

Comment: `pmin(unlist(a[-1],use.names=FALSE), a[,1][row(a[-1])]) `
gives me 
    `[1] 1 2 2 1 2 3`
Rather than the desired.

Comment: @user2065472  Look, you haven't showed a reproducible example earlier.  THis gives the expected output as per the example I showed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version with `sapply` and `ifelse` (which is vectorised, woo), which is likely faster, and deals with `NA` values in a predictable way:

```
sapply(X = seq(to = ncol(x = net)), FUN = function(j){
  net[,j] <- ifelse(test = net[,1] < net[,j], yes = net[,1], no = net[,j])
})
```

Some sample data

```
net <- head(airquality)
net
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
```

results in:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   41   41  7.4   41    5    1
[2,]   36   36  8.0   36    5    2
[3,]   12   12 12.0   12    5    3
[4,]   18   18 11.5   18    5    4
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]   28   NA 14.9   28    5    6
```

Note: I specified pretty much all argument names, as I've found this makes most code faster. If you don't care about time, a simpler [possibly more readable] version:

```
sapply(seq(ncol(net)), function(j){
    net[,j] <- ifelse(net[,1] < net[,j], net[,1], net[,j])
})
```